# SpriteKit SKAction.playSoundFile - waitForCompletion is not waiting

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am doing some SpriteKit game development in Swift2. I have a 2 part audio sentence (both parts are calculated based on the actual game situation) and I want to play part 2 after part 1 is finished.

These two lines of sound play immediately at the same time

```
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("question-part-a.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("question-part-b.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
```

But then, what is the parameter `waitForCompletion: true` good for?

I could work around this with a completion handler, when using the `runAction(action: SKAction, completion block: () -> Void)` but again, what then does the waitForCompletion parameter?

Maybe it is a complete missunderstanding on my side. Could anybody give me a hint?

Thanks in advance
Cheers
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of `waitForDuration`. In the apple docs, this is what it means -

> wait
>   If true, the duration of this action is the same as the length of the audio playback. If false, the action is considered to have completed immediately.

So if you want to run it in order, do this.

```
let action1 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("question-part-a.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
let action2 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("question-part-b.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
runAction(SKAction.sequence([
            action1,
            action2
            ]))
```

In your case, running the actions without putting them in an SKAction.sequence means that the compiler executes both lines of code simultaneously. The same result would be achieved if you set `wait` to `false` for `action1` and ran my code.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot! I thought might be a sequence thing but couldn't get a hook on it. Supercool. Cheers John